# Python Loop: Index out of range ERROR

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extremely new to Python, this is, in fact, my first ever made program. It's a simple web crawler that is making its way through a website's sitemap and collection data on the way. This loop will run a lot of times without any problems, every file will run this loop over 3000 times. After around 100 files I get an index out of range error and I have no idea why. Here is the loop that is giving problems:

```
for item in soup.find_all('loc'):
    newsItem = {
        'Category': '',
        'Title':    '',
        'Url':      ''
    }

    newsItem['Category'] = list(filter(None, item.text.replace(
        'http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))[0].title()
    newsItem['Title'] = list(filter(None, item.text.replace(
        'http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))[2].replace('-', ' ').title()
    newsItem['Url'] = item.text
    newsItems.append(newsItem)
    print_progress(counter, len(soup.find_all('loc')), 'Progress:')
    counter += 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "theVerge.py", line 52, in <module>
    'http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))[2].replace('-', ' ').title()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the stacktrace of the exception you see. One guess is that you're hitting a URL that doesn't have multiple `/` in it? So you get an exception when you try to extract the `Title` attribute...

Comment: Why don't you use a try-except block?

Comment: @t.m.adam, Yeah it is what I did in the end. It seems that in 1.2m loop runs there was 1 url that had no content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a traceback, my best guess would be this line:

```
newsItem['Title'] = list(filter(None, item.text.replace('http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))[2].replace('-', ' ').title()
```

I'm guessing whatever is the result of

```
newsItem['Title'] = list(filter(None, item.text.replace('http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))
```

Doesn't have 3 items inside, so the [2] index is out of range.

Oh, and by the way...that is some really gnarly string replace lines you have. For the sake of readability, you may want to break these up or find a better way do to this. Reading this code, I have no idea what

```
list(filter(None, item.text.replace('http://www.nu.nl', '').replace('.html', '').split('/')))[2].replace('-', ' ').title()
```

would do even if I had an example of input :P

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the url's look like this: http://www.nu.nl/selectie/4090934/voorbeschouwing-zestiende-tour-france-etappe.html. What I am doing is extracting the category after the first / and taking the title after the ID.

Comment: Ah. I think in this case, you may want to try regex pattern matching, it _may_ be easier to do this than a bunch of splits.

Comment: Is there a easy way to this with regex?